# Swift3 parameter outside repeat-while loop

Tags: function, scope, swift3

I want to create a deck of 10 cards from a set with multiple suits. However, there might be only some suits available.
I have therefore created a function `validCards() -> [Card]` that should pick 10 valid cards from the deck and return them as an array of cards. 
It does this by repeating to pick a card until it is valid:

```
func validCards() -> [Card] {
    let availableSuits: [String] = ["Diamond"]
    let deck: [Card] = Card.deck()
    var validDeck: [Card] = []
    for i in 0...10 {
        repeat {
            let (card, index) = deck.randomElement()
        } while !availableSuits.contains(card.suit) "|ERROR: Use of unresolved identifier card"
        validDeck.append(card) "|ERROR: Use of unresolved identifier card"
    }
    return validDeck
}
```

The only possible reason for the errors in line 8 and 9 (as far as I know) is that the variable is local inside the `repeat {}` loop.
However, swift does not let me to simply write `public var`, it throws an error "Attribute public can only be applied in a non-local scope.

Can someone help me?
Thanks a lot in advance,
Narusan

PS: I have a struct that defines `Card`, it is working perfectly fine, and also the Array Extension `randomElement` works.

Comment: `let (card, index)` is inside `repeat` block so it is not available outside that block, You need to declare tuple before repeat block like `var (card, index): (Card, Int)`

Comment: Also it is looks like `suit` is String property, so you need to use contains with your `availableSuits` Array.

Comment: Yeah, i just noticed that too. Thanks a lot

Comment: Welcome mate :)

Comment: One more thing: How do I write the `!=` when i use `array.contains()` ?

Comment: It is like `!availableSuits.contains(card.suit)`

Comment: Thanks. Coming from python, I tried `not availaleSuits.contains(card.suit)`

Comment: What was that down vote for? Please explain so I can improve my next question.

Comment: Wasn't blaming you. It's just a bit unhelpful if a stranger comes by, casts a down vote and leaves without saying anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a forward declaration so that the scope of `card` is not limited solely to the `repeat` block:

```
func validCards() -> [Card] {
    let availableSuits = ["Diamond"]
    let deck = Card.deck()
    var validDeck = [Card]()
    for i in 0...10 {
        let card: Card
        let index: Index
        repeat {
           (card, index) = deck.randomElement()
        } while card.suit != availableSuits "|ERROR: Use of unresolved identifier card"
        validDeck.append(card) "|ERROR: Use of unresolved identifier card"
    }
    return validDeck
}
```

Comment: Haha, how stupid of me not to think of this. Of course it has to be done that way. I'll accept your answer as soon as possible (10 minutes after the question has been asked)

Comment: This is a solution to your exact question, but Nirav's suggestion is much better

Comment: Thanks for the honesty. I myself ended up doing it Nirav's way, but your answer was more extensive!

Comment: @Narusan Yeah, I saw that there would be value in demonstrating forward declaration to fix an issue like this